# OAuth2 + InAppPurchase how I suppose to use them together?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-play, google-oauth

I am using InAppPurchases. I have connected OAuth and I got a token from there. But when I am making that call `POST https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/packageName/purchases/subscriptions/subscriptionId/tokens/token:cancel` It gives me error

```
"error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "errors": [
        {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
        }
        ],
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
        }
        }
```

How I can use my OAuth token to make a HTTP request to the Play Market?

Comment: Show [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The issue can arise on many levels. But looking at the response result I can tell you that you did not add a header named "Authorization". Header is a key-value pair and should look like "Authorization": "Bearer TOKEN_HERE". Note: "Bearer" is just a token type. It can be different, but most likely this is the one you should use. [HTTP Get example](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#http-get-examples) of OAuth request.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu can you please share with me example of the request?

Comment: I shared one. The link is at the end of my first commentary. If you need an example in a specific language then share what you have implemented until now and I'll try my best to give you an understandable example.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu i mean how I can send that HTTP `POST https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/packageName/purchases/subscriptions/subscriptionId/tokens/token:cancel` with OAuth?